# Enabling MediaPlayerBuffering event to be fired in android-vlc

Tags: android, vlc, libvlc

I would like to subscribe for the MediaPlayer buffering event in the android vlc app.

I edited the EventHandler class and uncommented the event constant.

```
public static final int MediaPlayerBuffering            = 0x103; // ** uncommented this**
public static final int MediaPlayerPlaying                = 0x104;
```

I then added the the variable in libvlcjni.c

```
libvlc_event_manager_t *ev = libvlc_media_player_event_manager(mp);
static const libvlc_event_type_t mp_events[] = {
    libvlc_MediaPlayerPlaying,
    libvlc_MediaPlayerPaused,
    libvlc_MediaPlayerEndReached,
    libvlc_MediaPlayerStopped,
    libvlc_MediaPlayerVout,
    libvlc_MediaPlayerPositionChanged,
    libvlc_MediaPlayerEncounteredError,
    libvlc_MediaPlayerBuffering // **added this here**
};
```

recompiled the jni to get the so file and then built the vlc app but the event never seems to fire off.

Where else do I have to link to get the event fired when there is a buffering event due to lack of bandwidth.

I can see in logcat that it prints 1001 ms buffered in 6ms. But that is coming from the lower layer and not the java layer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

had to add this in the libvlcjni.c file

```
else if(ev->type == libvlc_MediaPlayeBuffering) {
    /* For determining the vout/ES track change */
    jstring sData = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "data");
    (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, bundle, putFloat, sData, ev->u.media_player_buffer.new_cache);
    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, sData);
}
```

hope this helps someone

Comment: Where did you implement this in the libvlcjni file? I am getting an error 'union' <anonymous> const' no member named 'media_player_buffer'...sorry I literally have very little experience with JNI.

Comment: just search for the event types I don't exactly remember the location now. You can find a list of else if blocks .. just plant this event more :)

Answer (score 2):

`else if(ev->type == libvlc_MediaPlayerBuffering) {
    /* For determining the vout/ES track change */
    jstring sData = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "data");
    (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, bundle, putFloat, sData, ev->u.media_player_buffering.new_cache);
    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, sData);
}`

The answer is ev->u.media_player_buffering.new_cache

In the VLC file mediaPlayer.c 
I found this code:

```
`else if( newval.i_int == INPUT_EVENT_CACHE )
   {
    event.type = libvlc_MediaPlayerBuffering;
    event.u.media_player_buffering.new_cache = (int)(100 * var_GetFloat( p_input, "cache" ));
    libvlc_event_send( p_mi->p_event_manager, &event );
}
```

`

and in libvlc_events.h

`/* media instance */
      struct
        {
        float new_cache;
        } media_player_buffering;`

Then, I compiled it and it worked.  Special thanks to my boy Tracy on the coast!